# Where can I access the source code for gridworld actors?

Tags: java, methods, location, gridworld

The title says it all really.  I'm trying to find and modify the critter source code, but I don't know where it's located on my Windows computer.  I have gridworld and all, but the closest I get is critter.class.  Searching my computer has done nothing too; it pops up the oh-so-helpful "Nothing found" message, and just ticks me off.  Does anybody know where the source files are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Critter.java` file is in this folder: `GridWorldCode\framework\info\gridworld\actor`.

There is a folder containing `ChameleonCritter.java` and `CrabCritter.java` at this location: `GridWorldCode\projects\critters`.

Just edit any of these files with a text editor (Notepad++).

I hope this helps.